# HQL Query using group by

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following class structure FlowerDAO with the fields (mapped using Hibernate):

- id
- unitPrice
- name
- color

  How can i create an hql query to obtain the flower(s) for each color that has(ve) the minimum unit price on that color?

I have tried this, but it doesn't work

```
from FlowerDAO as f where f.unitPrice<= (select min(f2.unitPrice) from FlowerDAO as f2 where f2.color=f.color)
group by f.color
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is comparing a single value to a set of results. Try replacing the <= with an 'in', so your query will read:

```
from FlowerDAO as f 
  where f.unitPrice in 
    (select min(f2.unitPrice) from FlowerDAO as f2 where f2.color=f.color)
```

Also, I've removed the 'group by' from the end, since that will only provide one result for each colour, and you mention in the question flower(s). You may want to use

```
order by f.color
```

instead?